# Case sensitivity of standard fields

Tags: standard-objects, standard-field

How can I find standard fields in standard objects are Case Sensitive ? What's the default value Case Sensitive or Case Insensitive ?

Comment: are you talking about field API or field values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All field API names in Salesforce, standard and custom, are *case insensitive*. That's the case when you're using Apex, at least.

There doesn't appear to be any official documentation to corroborate that, but it's easy enough to verify for yourself.

```java
// Demonstrating that fields in SOQL queries are case-insensitive
// You'll need to replace my custom Account_Status__c field with a custom field
//   of your own.
List<Account> acctsList = [SELECT Id, Type, AcCoUnT_sTaTuS__c FROM Account LIMIT 1];
acctsList = [SELECT iD, TYPE, account_status__C FROM Account LIMIT 1];

// The order I debug the different possibilities in might look weird, but
//   there is a pattern to it.
// Only 1 letter changes its capitalization state from one line to the next.
// There isn't really much point to it here, it was just a good mental exercise.
// In boolean logic, doing this allows you to create a Karnaugh Map, which can
//   be used to simplify boolean logic.
system.debug(acctsList[0].id);
system.debug(acctsList[0].Id);
system.debug(acctsList[0].ID);
system.debug(acctsList[0].iD);

system.debug(acctsList[0].type);
system.debug(acctsList[0].Type);
system.debug(acctsList[0].TYpe);
system.debug(acctsList[0].tYpe);
system.debug(acctsList[0].tYPe);
system.debug(acctsList[0].TYPe);
system.debug(acctsList[0].TYPE);
system.debug(acctsList[0].tYPE);
system.debug(acctsList[0].tYpE);
system.debug(acctsList[0].TYpE);
system.debug(acctsList[0].TypE);
system.debug(acctsList[0].typE);
system.debug(acctsList[0].tyPE);
system.debug(acctsList[0].TyPE);
system.debug(acctsList[0].TyPe);
system.debug(acctsList[0].tyPe);

// I'm not so masochistic as to type out all the possibilities for my custom field,
// nor so sadistic to make you read it all.
system.debug(acctsList[0].ACCOUNT_STATUS__c);
system.debug(acctsList[0].account_StatuS__C);
```

SObject names, Type names, Class names, method names, and variable names are also case-insensitive in Apex.

```java
List<Account> acctsList = new LiSt<ACcoUNt>();
AcCtSlIsT = new liST<ACCOUNT>();
ACCTSList = [SELECT iD, TYPE, Account_STATUS__C FROM AccounT LIMIT 1];

system.debug(acctsList.SiZe());
```

That said, just because you *can* use any combination of cases doesn't mean that you *should*. Picking a standard casing scheme, like

- SObject and class names start with a capital letter
- Method names and variable names start with a lower-case letter and
  useCamelCasing
- SObject fields are Title_Case_With_Underscores__c

and *sticking to it* make it easier to read/write your code (and also prevent you from getting lazy and running into trouble with other programming languages).